# What does ?. do in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax, conditional-statements

What does "?." syntax do in Dart language? I have here an example from Flutter's scaffold.dart code:

```
_drawerKey.currentState?.open();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a null safe operator.

> Use ?. when you want to call a method/getter on an object IF that
> object is not null (otherwise, return null).

```
_drawerKey.currentState?.open();
```

Call `open()` only if it's not null.

More info: https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb

Answer (score 2):

> To guard access to a property or method of an object that might be null, put a question mark (?) before the dot (.):

```
myObject?.anyProperty
```

The preceding code is equivalent to the following:

```
(myObject != null) ? myObject.anyProperty: null
```

You can chain multiple uses of ?. together in a single expression:

```
myObject?.anyProperty?.anyMethod()
```

The preceding code returns null (and never calls anyMethod()) if either myObject or myObject.anyProperty is null.

For more, read [offcial docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#conditional-property-access),